The Lamb was slain before creation?
Heb 9:26 and Revelation 13:8 seem to be saying Christ was slain since creation. How do I reconcile this with his physical death and resurrection which happened many years after creation?

Rev 13:8  And all that dwell upon the earth shall worship him, whose
names are not written in the Book of Life of the Lamb, slain from the
foundation of the world.
Hebrew 9:26 For then must he often have suffered since the foundation
of the world: but now once in the end of the world hath he appeared to
put away sin by the sacrifice of himself

